# Path Of Current In A Wire

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

Why does current follow the path of least resistance? Will all  current pass through a wire with $0$ resistance in a junction leaving other resistive wires with no current?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does current follow the path of least resistance?

Current *doesn't* follow the path of least resistance.  Please forget that you ever heard that and if you hear someone else say that, respond with something like this:

If there are two parallel connected resistors with resistance $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively, the current *divides* between the two paths such that the path with *smallest* resistance has *largest* current through.

This is simply due to Ohm's law and, in particular, the fact that parallel connected circuit elements have identical voltage across (by definition!).

With voltage $V$ across, the current through each resistor is given by Ohm's law:

$$I_1 =  \frac{V}{R_1}$$

$$I_2 =  \frac{V}{R_2}$$

and now it's clear that the smaller resistance has the largest current through.  Denoting the *total* current $I = I_1 + I_2$, we easily derive the *current division* formula:

$$I_1 = I\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

$$I_2 = I\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

which again shows that the smaller resistance has the largest current through.  Note that if (just) one of the resistances is zero, then *all* of the current is through the zero ohm resistor.  For example, if $R_1 = 0$ then

$$I_1 = I\frac{R_2}{0 + R_2} = I$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Think of it like a pipe system with water.

If the pipe splits in two, one having a "squeezed" constriction and the other being much wider, then most water will go through the wide one. Infinite resistance corresponds to fully closing the constriction (no water passes), and 0 resistance corresponds to having the wide pipe infinitely wider than the other (all water would go there).